# create unique list from multi servers

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to create an inventory of my park.
form this exemple, I'm getting the serveur name and linux's version

in my inventory, there is a group with my servers. (listeServers)

I want to execute this task and finaly, show one complet liste with all of my servers (in only one var)

```
- hosts: listeServers
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    bilan: ['inventory']
  tasks:
    - name: "Unix version"
      shell: "echo Server : `uname -n` - `lsb_release -d -s`"
      register: unix_version    
    - name: "add to bilan"
      set_fact: 
        bilan: "{{ bilan + [ unix_version.stdout ] }}"
    - debug: var=bilan
```

at the moment, each server has its own variable.
and it gives:

```
10:15:06  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
10:15:06  ok: [serveur3_apache] => {
10:15:06      "bilan": [
10:15:06          "inventory",
10:15:06          "Server : server03 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
10:15:06      ]
10:15:06  }
10:15:06  ok: [serveur4_middle] => {
10:15:06      "bilan": [
10:15:06          "inventory",
10:15:06          "Server : server04 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
10:15:06      ]
10:15:06  }
10:15:06  ok: [serveur5_middle] => {
10:15:06      "bilan": [
10:15:06          "inventory",
10:15:06          "Server : server05 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
10:15:06      ]
10:15:06  }
10:15:06  ok: [serveur6_postgres] => {
10:15:06      "bilan": [
10:15:06          "inventory",
10:15:06          "Server : server06 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
10:15:06      ]
10:15:06  }
```

I would like them all to write to the same variable.
and the content of this variable is:

```
"inventoryM",
"Server : server03 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
"Server : server04 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
"Server : server05 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
"Server : server06 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

[*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables from the *hostvars*. Use [*ansible_play_hosts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

```yaml
    - name: Create list bilan
      set_fact: 
        bilan: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                   map('extract', hostvars, ['unix_version', 'stdout'] }}"
```